# Regular expression contain either less then symbol or greater then symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui

I want to validate string which having 0-9,A-Z, a-z and -, _ and space( ). now i want to allow < or > optionally.

string should not start and end with < or >

var ValueExpression = new RegExp('^[0-9a-zA-Z _-]+$');

allowed strings are - a>10 ,a<10 or a10 but not html tag , ><

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression that is valid in Perl (the testing software says it is also valid in js but couldn't validate.

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\ ]+)(([<>]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\ ]+))?)$/
```

It accepts only one ocurrence of "<" or ">" but not both.

Captured groups: 
 1. - everything;
 2. - Right most set of values including operator (optional)
 3. - Operator (optional - Depend on the second group)
 4. - Right hand side value (optional - Depend on the second group)